# Tabs Delegate not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do l get the click on this class `ui-icon-close`?

I have the following HMTL

```
<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" >
   <li class="active">
       <a href="#List" data-toggle="tab">My List 
           <span  class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'></span> 
       </a>           
   </li>
</ul>
```

And the following Jquery/Javascript

```
$('#tabs a').delegate( "#.ui-icon-close", "click", function(){
    console.log('tabs');
 });
```

Comment: @RayonDabreI have made it .ui-icon-close, but still not working

Answer (score 3):

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R85tE/523/)**

You have an extra `#` in `#.ui-icon-close` should be `".ui-icon-close"`:

```
$('#tabs a').delegate( ".ui-icon-close", "click", function(){
    console.log('tabs');
});
```

> As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.

So you should use `on()` instead of `delegate()` and reverse the position of the event `click` and selector `.ui-icon-close` :

```
$('#tabs a').on( "click", ".ui-icon-close", function(){
    console.log('tabs');
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but it is not working I am using JQUERY 2.2.1

Comment: `.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )`

Comment: Thanks guys.. It is still not working.. I have '$('#tabs a').click (function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); });' Is this having effect on the above click?

Comment: @ErnestAppiah, There is nothing in the span element to be clicked...Provided example is working for me [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/6jqqv345/)

Comment: Check working fiddle in my updated answer @ErnestAppiah. and prevent default should not have any effect to the close icon.